# Split CSV file in records and save as a csv file format - Apache NIFI

Tags: apache, csv, apache-nifi

What I want to do is the following...

I want to divide the input file into registers, convert each record into a
file and leave all the files in a directory.

My .csv file has the following structure:

```
    ERP,J,JACKSON,8388 SOUTH CALIFORNIA ST.,TUCSON,AZ,85708,267-3352,,ALLENTON,MI,48002,810,710-0470,369-98-6555,462-11-4610,1953-05-00,F,
ERP,FRANK,DIETSCH,5064 E METAIRIE AVE.,BRANDSVILLA,MO,65687,252-5592,1176 E THAYER ST.,COLUMBIA,MO,65215,557,291-9571,217-38-5525,129-10-0407,1/13/35,M,
```

As you can see it doesn't have Header row.

Here is my flow.
[image]

My problem is that when the Split Proccessor divides my csv into flows with 400 lines, it isn't save in my output directory.

It's first time using NIFI, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `RecordReader controller service` is configured correctly(delimiter..etc) to read the incoming flowfile.

- Records per split value as 1

You need to use **`UpdateAttribute`** processor before **`PutFile`** processor to change the filename to unique value (like UUID) *unless* if you are configured **`PutFile`** processor **Conflict Resolution strategy** as `Ignore`

- The reason behind changing filename is **`SplitRecord`** processor is going to have `same filename` for all the splitted flowfiles.

***Flow:***

[image]

I tried your case and **flow worked as expected**, Use [this](https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/SplitRecord.xml) template for your reference and `upload` to your NiFi instance, Make changes as per your requirements.